# alphabetically sort TypeScript interface keys

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

Is there a way to automatically sort TypeScript interface keys? I'm already using Prettier and VSCode so ideally the solution would be with those but I'm open to any solutions.

For example,

```
// before
interface MyInterface {
  foo: number;
  bar: number;
  baz: number;
}

// after sort
interface MyInterface {
  bar: number;
  baz: number;
  foo: number;
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In VS Code; you can simply select the lines you want to sort and then `CMD + SHIFT + P` (`Ctrl + Shift + P` on Windows) and search for `Sort lines Ascending/Descending`.

[image]

Comment: This will not work for keys that have nested values that flow over multiple lines.

Comment: Hi @TimKrins, that's right.  This is for sorting a list of single line items.  You could consider abstracting out multi-line expressions inside objects to a variable.

Answer (score 13):

Lots of plugins are available for VSCode. "Sort" by "Henrik Sjööh" works nicely.

After installing the plugin, highlight the interface and press `alt+shift+s` (`option+shift+s` on MacOS) and the interface will be reordered.

Comment: there is a lot of manual effort to sort like this...we should be able to run sort on entire file

Comment: @RahulYadav I agree. this is something that should be accomplished automatically by prettier.  It's been 2.5 years since my original question.  If you find something new like a plugin for prettier, please post the answer here.

Comment: > The first requirement of Prettier is to output valid code that has the exact same behavior as before formatting.

By principle, Prettier won't do this, since objects are also used as maps, and there are use cases where the _"insertion order"_ (for the lack of a better term) -- matters.  Just my $0.02.

Comment: @RichardMichaelCoo everything you said is correct, but about object literals. Question is about interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

A perhaps better approach would be to enforce such a thing, especially if you are working on a team. Linters actually have support for this and it's called object-sort-keys for tslint and sort-keys for eslint. They also come with auto fixes within VS Code, so if you activate this rule on any linter, you can automatically fix the ordering of the keys. (You could even do this on Save -> fix all linting issues on save).

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/sort-keys

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/object-literal-sort-keys/ (careful, tslint will be deprecated in favor of eslint soon)

Comment: to clarify, `object-sort-keys` would generally apply to an Interface?

Comment: Except afaik, eslint isn't going to support a quick fix rule for this - https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7714

Comment: There's a fork that allows automatic fixing! https://github.com/forivall/eslint-plugin-sort-keys-plus

Answer (score 1):

Many of these answers are for sorting Objects, not TypeScript Interfaces.

For TypeScript Interfaces you should be using Eslint and this eslint plugin: [eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys](https://github.com/infctr/eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys).

Follow their setup instructions to have Eslint throw an error or warning when TypeScript Interfaces keys are unsorted.

It also comes with an autofix.

So you can add this to your Visual Studio Code `settings.json` file and it will automatically fix the ESlint error, which in this case means automatically sorting Interfaces for you.

```
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort object keys alphabetically, I am using the extension [Sort JS Object](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=debens.sort-js-object).