# Sorting angular routes by alphabitical order

Tags: angular, frontend

I have a route file with multiple elements, and i need to sort the routes table by alphabitical order.

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BlButtonPageComponent } from './bl-button-page/bl-button-page.component';
import { BlCalloutPageComponent } from './bl-callout-page/bl-callout-page.component';
import { BlIconPageComponent } from './bl-icon-page/bl-icon-page.component';
import { BlMatformfieldPageComponent } from './bl-matformfield-page/bl-matformfield-page.component';
import { BlSplitButtonPageComponent } from './bl-split-button-page/bl-split-button-page.component';
import { BlTransverseMenuPageComponent } from './bl-transverse-menu-page/bl-transverse-menu-page.component';
import { BlVerticalMenuPageComponent } from './bl-vertical-menu-page/bl-vertical-menu-page.component';
import { StyleModule } from './style.module';
import { BlBreadCrumbPageComponent } from './bl-bread-crumb-page/bl-bread-crumb-page.component';
import { HyperlinkPageComponent } from './bl-hyperlink-page/hyperlink-page.component';
import { BlNotificationPageComponent } from './bl-notification-page/bl-notification-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'button', component: BlButtonPageComponent },
  { path: 'split-button', component: BlSplitButtonPageComponent },
  { path: 'callout', component: BlCalloutPageComponent },
  { path: 'icon', component: BlIconPageComponent },
  { path: 'matformfield', component: BlMatformfieldPageComponent },
  { path: 'verticalmenu', component: BlVerticalMenuPageComponent },
  { path: 'transversemenu', component: BlTransverseMenuPageComponent },
  { path: 'breadcrumb', component: BlBreadCrumbPageComponent },
  { path: 'hyperlink', component: HyperlinkPageComponent },
  { path: 'notification', component: BlNotificationPageComponent },
];


export const STYLE_ROUTES: ModuleWithProviders<StyleModule> =
  RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

I've tried to sort it on export but it's not working

```
export const STYLE_ROUTES: ModuleWithProviders<StyleModule> =
  RouterModule.forChild(routes.sort((a, b) => a.path.localeCompare(b.path)));
```

Comment: 1. why? and 2. why not just update it manually to be in alphabetical order?

Comment: We are trying to make a library of components, and there are multiple people working on it, therefore a lot of people forget and include the path randomly, so I've tried to think of a way to sort the paths dynamically.

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60952889/alphabetically-sort-typescript-interface-keys

Comment: Are you looking at ordering the routes at runtime because you're looping on them all to display the links or to order them in the code to have something a bit nicer as multiple people are working on them?

Comment: @maxime1992 I'm looking to order them at runtime.